# Unable to receive UDP packet on PC from Android phone

Tags: android, networking, udp

I am trying to establish a simple connection between a PC running a Java UDP server and an Android phone running a UDP client. Android says the package is sent, but the PC doesn't receive anything.

Both devices are under the same network, the PC is connected via Ethernet with IP 192.168.56.1 and the Android is connected via Wi-fi. The port is 2050 in both of them, and buffer size is 1024 in both of them. I am trying to send from Android phone a 4 digit PIN, plus the character #, plus a 4 digit acception code (0001 in this case), so the message would be something similar to 2348#0001. PC should receive the package and decode this message.

Server (PC) code (it stays forever in receive):

```
private boolean connect() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Waiting for PIN code...");
    String msg;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
    System.out.println("Received packet");
    msg = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
    String[] msgDecoded = msg.split("#");
    clientIP = packet.getAddress();

    if(msgDecoded[0].equals(password) && msgDecoded[1].equals(CONNECTION_ACCEPT_CODE)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Client (Android phone) code:

```
public void establishConnection(View view) throws Exception{

    /* Variable assignments and initializations */
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    serverIP = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipInput)).getText().toString();
    Log.d("Info", "IP ADDRESS: " + serverIP);
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
    final String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput)).getText().toString();
    String message = password + "#" + CONNECTION_ACCEPT_CODE;
    data = message.getBytes();
    final DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, DEFAULT_PORT);

    /* Send the data to the server */
    /* Needs to be done in another thread, otherwise NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown */
    Thread sendThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{ clientSocket.send(sendPacket); Log.d("TEST", "Sent" + sendPacket.getData().toString());}
            catch (Exception e){ Log.d("TEST", "EXCEPTION SENDING"); }
        }
    });
    sendThread.start();


    /* Now wait for server ACK */
    receiveData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    final DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

    /* Receive data from the server */
    /* Needs to be done in another thread, otherwise NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown */
    Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                Log.d("RECEIVED", receivePacket.getData().toString());
                String ack = new String(receivePacket.getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                /* If receive ACK go to next activity */
                if(ack.equals(ACK_ACCEPTED)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), KeylogActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IPADDR, serverIP);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PASSWD, password);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                /* If we don't, log error */
                // TODO: do actual job here
                else{
                    Log.d("[Error]", "Server rejected the connection: " + ack);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) { Log.d("ERROR", "Exception receiving: " + e); }
        }
    });
    receiveThread.start();
}
```

SendThread seems to work well, because it logs "Sent", but it has no effect on PC. Since PC server doesn't receive messages, it doesn't send anything either so the Android phone doesn't receive anything.

Comment: Is the phone on wifi or cellular?  Does the network, and all network between allow UDP (not all do)?  Is your router set to allow UDP to the PC's IP and port?  Most likely this is a network setup issue.

Comment: The phone is connected via wifi to the same network as the PC. How do I check if my router is set to allow UDP to that IP and port?

Comment: Depends on the router.  Go into its settings and look for anything that mentions UDP or port routing

Comment: It was a problem with the specified IP. I was using the VirtualBox one, I realised when trying to open the port. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that I was trying to connect to a VirtualBox Host-Only Network. I ran the command ipconfig on Powershell and saw my real IP. Changing the IP in the app to match the Ethernet interface one solved the problem for me.